# CURL posting to another domain SSL Certificate Error

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to use curl to an HTTPS address of an API.  The api simply displays a string result on the page posting to and does not return me my domain.  I'm not sure if there is another way to do it but figured CURL was the only solution.

Could it be possible this is only occuring on my localhost?

Error receiving:
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK

```
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);


//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

Result:
string 'SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed' (length=146)

Comment: do you mind sharing what was the response?
is the api using ssl 3.0 and above? usually when you curl from your server it starts with ssl 2.0 and this will cause problem.

Comment: Added the result above

Comment: See this link:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: 1) add the ssl into your approve list
ref: http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/
2) try curling method for tls
3) update your curl bundle file
ref: http://davidwalsh.name/php-ssl-curl-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, PHP attempts to certify the peer's certificate.

If you're sure you don't care, you can do this to see if the cURL request can fire, just for testing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before you execute the cURL call.

The proper way would be to actually set up the cURL call to use your server's existing CA certificates using `CURLOPT_CAPATH` or `CURLOPT_CAINFO`.

Comment: I tried that but the site is returning a 405 error

Comment: @Chad Hmm, 405 error means method is not allowed, meaning you should try using GET or PUT instead of POST.